# What happens when give field name without any condition in Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

When I run an SQL query with a field name only in where condition, what will be the default condition applicable to the field name?

```
Select * from tablename where fieldname;
```

Comment: count condition as false or null

Comment: What you won't get is a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

If you run

```
Select * from tablename where fieldname;
```

it will act as

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE fieldname IS NOT NULL
```

and **returns not null/empty data**

> **If you're run this in PhpMyAdmin column you specify will get highlighted and data with  no empty sets**

Answer (score 1):

The `WHERE` clause contains a boolean expression. Something like `a = b and c = d` for instance. If you have `where fieldname` then `fieldname` alone is that boolean expression. So `fieldname` would typically be a boolean column such as in

```
select * from client where is_active;
```

If it is not a boolean column, then MySQL will try to convert:

1. A number will first get truncated to integer. Then a zero is considered false, all other numbers are considered true.
2. A string will get converted to number first, where MySQL reads from left to right (e.g. `'012.3AB'` gets converted to `12.3`). Then the number will get converted to boolean as explained above.
3. A date will get converted to number (e.g. `date '1999-02-03'` becomes `19990203`). Then the number will get converted to boolean as explained above.

(I don't know, however, whether these conversions are guaranteed to be applied thus. This is merely what I have observed.)

Generally it doesn't make much sense to use  `where fieldname` with a non-boolean `fieldname`. MySQL's silent conversion is quite error-prone; it's easy to simply forget the right part of a comparision and not notice. It would be better in my opinion did MySQL raise an error instead.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this on w3schools sql editor:

[image]

**There was no syntax error**

To re-verify I used the sql syntax checker to get the below result

[image]

If you try **select * from customers where city is not null;**

then obviously you will get all not null records as below.

[image]